# Event MyEvent has ID 2 which is already in use

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric, etw

I am implementing event tracing using EWT in a Service Fabric application and are faced with these errors

ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource MyCompany-ServiceFabricApplication-LiveDataReader: Event OnCommandMessageReceived has ID 2 which is already in use

The "OnCommandMessageReceived" is my custom event

```
[Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Verbose, Message = "Queue client created '{0}'")]
    public void OnQueueClientCreated(string queueClientName)
    {
        if (IsEnabled())
        {
            WriteEvent(2, queueClientName);
        }
    }
```

I have multiple/many of these errors and I have tried to messing around with numbers but ...

Is there some Powershell command or else that can tell what IDs are in use or is there a safe range or something?

PS: When that event is fired i can see it in visual studio diagnostic events viewer but the Message is empty. It would be cool if it displayed the message from the payload. Is that possible?
[image]

Comment: do you have any other event that uses Id of 2? change the ID to 3 or an other "free" Id.

Comment: I have made all the ids unique across all services. There error is gone now. Thank you

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Comment: You can use Event Source from NuGet package. It is preferable because it has some small compile time checks that will show such issues with duplicate event id or incorrect keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ETW Events must have an [unique ID per provider](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/12/21/why-doesnt-my-eventsource-produce-any-events/). So look if you have other events with ID 2 and change tie ID to a different value.

Comment: The error has gone after making all IDs unique per provider